# Why co-authored commits do not show up on contributions in a repo?

Tags: github

I only get the PRs that have been merged counted towards my contribution commits in a repo.

Comment: removed git tag as git doesn't know about co-authoring. that's a github thing.

Comment: is your email address menitoned in the commit message?  see 
 https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors

Comment: Yes it is .....